# Хранимая процедура,проблема со вставкой русских символов sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Проблема при вставке русских символов.
Использую MS SQL server

Вот хранимая процедура

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_NewMessageRequest  
@Email_letter varchar(100),
@Name_letter   varchar(100),
@Phone_letter varchar(30), 
@Descript_letter varchar(500),
@Date_letter datetime,
@Check_letter bit

AS   
BEGIN   
          SET NOCOUNT ON;
          select @Date_letter = GETDATE();
          INSERT INTO dbo.NewLetter(Email_letter, Name_letter, Phone_letter, Descript_letter, Date_letter, Check_letter)
          VALUES
          (@Email_letter, @Name_letter, @Phone_letter, @Descript_letter, @Date_letter, @Check_letter);
END
```

При ее выполнении русские символы в БД вставляются таким образом - ??????.

Выполнение процедуры

```
USE [NewMainDBForCRUD]
GO

DECLARE @return_value Int

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[SP_NewMessageRequest]
    @Email_letter = N'выаыва',
    @Name_letter = N'ываыва',
    @Phone_letter = N'выаваы',
    @Descript_letter = N'ыва',
    @Date_letter = N'11.11.2017',
    @Check_letter = 'false'
SELECT  @return_value as 'Return Value'
GO
```

Comment: почему у вас параметры типа `varchar` передаете вы им `N'строка'`, когда `N` укзывает, что это `nvarchar`. И что там по итогу за поля  в таблице?

Comment: да, точно надо изменить тип

Comment: я бы еще задумался зачем `bit` передавать как `'false'`

Comment: Нет разницы 1 0 or false true

Comment: Все спасибо, проглядел тип. Все ок теперь